# CakePHP project for multiple websites

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I've created a CMS with CakePHP.

I am using this CMS for multiple clients, all on different servers.

The base code is for every client the same. I change the public template to their needs. So basiccaly only a few files are different.

How can I manage this on my local (testing) server.

I don't want to duplicate the all files for every client. So if I update the code, it is only done on one location and then uploaded to serveral locations. I don't want to change it per client.

How do you manage this?

Comment: You could sync the application to all servers when the source is updated using a shell script and rsync. Or put clients on vhosts on the same server accessing your production code from one location creating a multi-tenant application. Depends on your security and client needs.

Answer (score 2):

- Put the core code in a repository `ted\my-fancy-cms`.
- Put each template in a theme, themes are like plugins (read the docs)
- Register each theme in their own namespace `my-fancy-cms\client1-theme`
- Check the core out on each installation and `composer require my-fancy-cms\client1-theme`

  - Alternatively you can also use branches  or forks of a theme and check that branch / fork out.

In your local copy you can checkout whatever theme you want then and the best is that everything is in a version control system as well and easy to switch. All of this should be super easy to maintain as well.